# Transform Text to Number wrongly formatted after Google Query

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I query data from a database (using Google query on G.spreadsheet).

However, once the query is done, 3 columns out of 6 (where each column is filled by dates) are formatted as Text and not date and the cells are not responsive to any format request I do.

Is there something I should be aware of between query and formatting?

```
=QUERY('JV Database'!A1:Z7394,"select* where (G contains '"&C1&"') and (((R > date '"&A1&"') and (R < date '"&B1&"')) or ((S > date '"&A1&"') and (S < date '"&B1&"')) or ((T > date '"&A1&"') and (T < date '"&B1&"')) or ((W > date '"&A1&"') and (W < date '"&B1&"')) or ((V > date '"&A1&"') and (V < date '"&B1&"'))) and (D contains '"&D1&"') and (C contains '"&E1&"') and (A contains '"&F1&"') ")
```

Cheers

Comment: Can yo provide a link to a sample sheet and also the query you are using?

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide the link as data are confidential. I added the query function above

Answer (score 1):

The QUERY function also allows you to format.

Try adding `format A 'dd/mm/yyyy', B 'dd/mm/yyyy'`, or however you like them, at the very end just before `")`. I think you also need to select all your columns to format them `select A,B,C` etc, I'm not sure.